# How can I modify this JS function so that it runs whenever the field is equal a certain length?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a function that currently runs whenever the user clicks/tabs out of the employee_number field. I would like it to run whenever the length of the numbers entered is equal to 6, without having to leave the field, since when I try using the tab, it conflicts with loading the next field which is a drop-down that is part of the function ran.

I tried by running it using .change and putting the constraint within the function, but it did not work and I don't know what else to try.

**enter_exit.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load core_tags staticfiles %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-employee-activity-lookup-url="{% url 'operations:employee_activity_search' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="employee-name" style="margin-bottom: 10px">&nbsp;</div>
                <label>Employee #</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}

            </div>

            <div=>
                <label>Work Area</label>
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div style="display: none" id="my-hidden-div">
                <label>Station</label>
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button>Enter Area</button>
                <button>Exit Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>

        // Grab the employee name and their current active work log (if any)
        $(document).on('blur', "#{{ form.employee_number.id_for_label }}", function(){
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr('data-employee-activity-lookup-url');
            var employeeId = $(this).val();
           # ... more fields ...

            if (employeeId !== "") {

              # .. Rest of function ...
        })
     </script>

{% endblock main %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using on blur have you tried using .keyup or .keydown?
Here's a simple version of it working in CodePen:

```
$("#test1").keydown(()=>{
  if($("#test1").val().length>6)
    console.log('6+');
})
```

https://codepen.io/orunnals/pen/JjoRGLX

Comment: I tried earlier but it would not call the function at all for some reason either

Comment: Have you tried changing your jQuery selector to be formatted in the way my code is? So instead of $(document).on, using $("#{{...")?
Additionally, is your jQuery wrapped inside a $(function () { }) call?